# In development based on Quickly, why do codes start with "from gi.repository import Gtk"?

Tags: application-development, gtk, quickly, pygtk

I am developing apps in Quickly. Default codes start with `from gi.repository import Gtk`. Why is it so and not simply `import gtk` for example?

The point is, a lot of tutorials, documentation and forums answers on the web are based on the second importation, as far as I have seen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`from gi.repository import Gtk` uses the new [PyGObject](https://live.gnome.org/PyGObject) instead of the older [PyGTK](http://pygtk.org/) that is used with `import gtk`.

Comment: Thank you. I am now reassured as far as the future of my apps is concerned, since I know that PyGObject is some sort of replacement for PyGtk. But this leads me also to ask other questions on Ask Ubuntu…